# How can I identify a strange character?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode

I am trying to identify a strange character I have found in a file I am working with:

```
$ cat file
�
$ od file
0000000 005353
0000002
$ od -c file
0000000 353  \n
0000002
$ od -x file
0000000 0aeb
0000002
```

The file is using ISO-8859 encoding and can't be converted to UTF-8:

```
$ iconv -f ISO-8859 -t UTF-8 file
iconv: conversion from `ISO-8859' is not supported
Try `iconv --help' or `iconv --usage' for more information.
$ iconv  -t UTF-8 file
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0
$ file file
file: ISO-8859 text
```

My main question is how can I interpret the output of `od` here? I am trying to use [this page](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi) which lets me translate between different character representations, but it tells me that `005353` as a "Hex code point" is `卓` which doesn't seem right and `0aeb` as a "Hex code point" is `૫` which, again, seems wrong.

So, how can I use any of the three options (`355`, `005353` or `0aeb`) to find out what character they are supposed to represent?

And yes, I did try with Unicode tools but it doesn't seem to be a valid UTF character either:

```
$ uniprops $(cat file)
U+FFFD ‹�› \N{REPLACEMENT CHARACTER}
    \pS \p{So}
    All Any Assigned Common Zyyy So S Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph X_POSIX_Graph
       GrBase Other_Symbol Print X_POSIX_Print Symbol Specials Unicode
```

if I understand the description of the Unicode U+FFFD character, it isn't a real character at all but a placeholder for a corrupted character. Which makes sense since the file isn't actually UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: EB could be δ in [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), or Ù in [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), or ë in [8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1); would any of those make sense? (`iconv` complains because you didn’t specify the source character set, so it uses your default which is probably UTF-8.)

Comment: @StephenKitt yes, `ë` is what I see when the data is used on another program! But how can I know this? Isn't it somewhere in the data I provide? How did you find it? Oh I had tried `iconv` with `-f ISO-8859` but it complained about `conversion from `ISO-8859' is not supported`.

Comment: Argh! I see, I needed to use just `eb` and ignore the `0x` hex indicator or whatever that is. My ignorance of this sort of thing is deep. Could you post an answer explaining that @StephenKitt?

Comment: Your crucial mistake here is that ISO-8859 is not the name of an encoding. It's a family of encodings; apparently, the one you are looking for is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @tripleee that is indeed very relevant, thanks. But how would knowing that have helped me identify the character?

Comment: Then your `iconv` would have succeeded; and/or you could have looked it up e.g. on Wikipedia. For this very specific encoding, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00eb/index.htm also works (Unicode is equivalent to ISO-8859-1 in the range 128-255, though of course no UTF encoding is compatible with it).

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184538/how-to-convert-unknown-8bit-file-to-utf8

Comment: @terdon 0a would be a separate character in ISO-8859-1 -- specifically, a newline.

Comment: if there's more context in the file, MS Word can guess the language and encoding quite correctly. I don't know if Libre Office Writer has that ability or not

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your file contains two bytes, EB and 0A in hex. It’s likely that the file is using a character set with one byte per character, such as [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1); in that character set, EB is ë:

```
$ printf "\353\n" | iconv -f ISO-8859-1
ë
```

Other candidates would be δ in [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), Ù in [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)...

`od -x`’s output is confusing in this case because of endianness; a better option is `-t x1` which uses single bytes:

```
$ printf "\353\n" | od -t x1
0000000 eb 0a
0000002
```

`od -x` maps to `od -t x2` which reads two bytes at a time, and on little-endian systems outputs the bytes in reverse order.

When you come across a file like this, which isn’t valid UTF-8 (or makes no sense when interpreted as a UTF-8 file), there’s no fool-proof way to automatically determine its encoding (and character set). Context can help: if it’s a file produced on a Western PC in the last couple of decades, there’s a fair chance it’s encoded in ISO-8859-1, -15 (the Euro variant), or Windows-1252; if it’s older than that, CP-437 and CP-850 are likely candidates. Files from Eastern European systems, or Russian systems, or Asian systems, would use different character sets that I don’t know much about. Then there’s EBCDIC... `iconv -l` will list all the character sets that `iconv` knows about, and you can proceed by trial and error from there.

(At one point I knew most of CP-437 and ATASCII off by heart, them were the days.)

Comment: OK, in the wikipedia page you link to, I can see that `ë` is described as `00EB` and `234`. What are those extra `00`? And why isn't it `355` as I expected from the `od` output? I am trying to get a more general answer about how I can use the `od` output to identify the character. Could you maybe explain something about interpreting hex codes and/or what information is needed to be able to identify an unknown character (encoding and whatever else)?

Comment: EB is 353 in octal (not 355). I’ll try to generalise...

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I meant `353`.  So the 353 is an octal representation, not decimal. Argh.

Comment: Yes, the “o” in `od` stands for octal ;-).

Comment: In any case, the `�` (U+FFFD) would be displayed by the terminal emulator as a substitute for that 0xeb byte that doesn't form a valid character in UTF-8. It's not clear why `uniprops $(cat file)` (missing quotes btw) would report that (I don't know about that `uniprops` command). `unicode "$(cat file)"` on Debian does output `Sequence '\xeb' is not valid in charset 'UTF-8'` as I'd expect.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `uniprops` is part of the `Unicode::Tussle` perl module and is a great tool for identifying unicode characters. Don't work so good with non-unicode, apparently :)

Comment: See also https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html#eb for a convenient table. `</plug>`

Comment: You make it sound like cp1252 replaced cp437 and cp850, but all three are used every day to this day. cp1252 is an ANSI encoding, which means it's used by Windows system calls. cp437 and cp850 are OEM encodings, meaning they are used by Windows consoles. (My machine uses cp1252 and cp850. Most Americans use cp1252 and cp437.)

Comment: @ikegami I’m talking about the likelihood of finding encodings used in files; I think CP-437 and 850 are much less common there than they used to be.

Comment: Windows used to call this ANSI, but it was never strictly correct usage, and my understanding is that they no longer use this term in this context.

Comment: @tripleee, I realized that while they are called ANSI encodings, it's a misnomer. But they are still called that, and they don't have a choice. Every function that accepts or returns a text string has an "A"NSI and a "W"ide variant. I suppose you could use another name that starts with "A" instead of "ANSI".

Comment: The `00EB` in Wikipedia's table is a shorthand for its Unicode code point, more usually written `U+00EB`.  They probably leave out the `U+` prefixes in these tables to reduce visual clutter.

Comment: Might also want to note that Windows-1252 is so commonly mislabeled as ISO-8859-1 that [HTML5 just assumes you meant the former instead of the latter](https://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-character-encoding).  It is therefore not possible to encode an HTML5 document in ISO-8859-1 in such a way that browsers will correctly decode it.

Answer (score 5):

Note that `od` is short for *octal dump*, so `005353` are the two bytes as octal word, `od -x` is `0aeb` in hexadecimal as word, and the actual contents of your file are the two bytes `eb` and `0a` in hexadecimal, in this order.

So both `005353` and `0aeb` can't just be interpreted as "hex code point".

`0a` is a line feed (LF), and `eb` depends on your encoding. `file` is just guessing the encoding, it could be anything. Without any further information where the file came from etc. it will be difficult to find out.

Comment: I realize this is because I don't understand how code points (or hex, really) work, but how can I know this? I usually use `od -c` since that produces output I can understand. How could I have used the `355` that produces to identify the character? And why is it printing `0aeb` instead of `eb0a` if `0a` is the newline?

Comment: @terdon endianness... See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to guess with 100% of accuracy the charset of text files.

Tools like **chardet**, **firefox**, **file -i** when there is no explicit charset information defined
(eg. if a HTML contains a meta charset=... in the head, things are easier)
will try to use heuristics that are not so bad if the text is big enough.

In the following, I demonstrate charset-detection with `chardet` (`pip install chardet` / `apt-get install python-chardet` if necessary).

```
$ echo "in Noël" | iconv -f utf8 -t latin1  | chardet
<stdin>: windows-1252 with confidence 0.73
```

After having good charset candidate, we can use `iconv`, `recode` or similar
to change the file charset to your "active" charset (in my case utf-8) and see if it guessed correctly...

```
iconv -f windows-1252  -t utf-8 file
```

Some charset (like iso-8859-3, iso-8859-1) have many chars in common -- sometimes it is not easy to see if we found the perfect charset...

So it is very important to have metadata associated with relevant text (eg XML).

Comment: Hmm. I can't reproduce it here, it just crashes. But in any case, isn't that simply telling me the encoding of the file? My issue is identifying the *character* not the file's encoding. That I already knew.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to understood the question (my usual problem is identifying the charset) . if you now the encoding, `iconv -f ... -t utf-8 ` will show you the chars?

Comment: No. I show the encoding right there. There was one particular character not supported by that encoding and it is that character I was trying to identify.

Comment: Iso-8859 is not the encoding!  the encoding is `iso-8850-1` .  iso-8859 is a iso standart the includes several chaset definitions. Try `file -i ...`

Comment: OK, thanks, that's good to know. Still not relevant here though. I didn't care about the encoding and still don't. I was trying to identify the character to figure out where it came from.

Comment: @terdon, sorry to insist, but, all the tricks you tried work with the right charset. Ex:  `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57896/discussion-between-terdon-and-jjoao).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Search in a file, a known (part of a ) String (i.E.: Begrüßung),
# by testing all encodings
#
[[ $# -ne 2 ]] && echo "Usage: encoding-finder.sh FILE fUnKy_CHAR_FOR_SURE_IN_FILE" && exit
FILE=$1
PATTERN=$2
for enc in $( iconv -l | sed 's/..$//') 
do 
    iconv -f $enc -t UTF-8 $FILE  2>/dev/null | grep -m 1 $PATTERN && echo $enc 
done
```

If I get a file, which contains, for Instance the Word Begrung, I can infer that Begrüßung might be meant. So I convert it by all known encodindgs and look, whether one is found, which converts it properly.

Usually, there are multiple encodings which seem to fit.

For longer files, you might cut a snippet instead of converting hundreds of pages.

So I would call it

```
encodingfinder.sh FILE Begrüßung
```

and the script tests, whether by converting it with the known encodings, which of them produce "Begrüßung".

To find such characters, less is usually of help, since funky characters often stand out. From the context, the right word to search for can usually be inferred. But we don't want to check with a hexeditor, what byte this is, and then visit endless tables of encodings, to find our offender. :)